# type Object Validation in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do schema validation in mongoose of type object and array, but I am not able to do that. Here is the schema:

```
var alertEmailSchema = new alertEmailSchema({
    templateId: { type: String, required: true,unique: true},
    templateName : { type: String, required: true},
    status: Boolean,
    frequency : { type: Object, required: true},
    recipientsEmailId : { type: [String], default: [], required: true},
    subject : { type: String, required: true},
    message : { type: String, required: true},
    description : String, 
    createdDate : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
    updatedDate : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
});

 var schemaValidation = newAlertEmail.validateSync();
```

Please tell me how can I do the validation for this.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want something like this:

```
var frequency  = new Schema({
    count: {
        type: Number
    },
    updateAt: {
        type: Date
    }
}, {
        _id: false // this will not create _id for this schema
    });

var alertEmailSchema  = new Schema({
    templateId: { type: String, required: true,unique: true},
    templateName : { type: String, required: true},
    status: Boolean,
    frequency : frequency, //this can be an array also [frequency]
    recipientsEmailId : { type: [String], default: [], required: true},
    subject : { type: String, required: true},
    message : { type: String, required: true},
    description : String, 
    createdDate : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
    updatedDate : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
});
```

Here, I created another schema known as **frequency** and used it in schema **alertEmailSchema**.